# my app breaks when page loads because the command it's not called

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I have a page where I bind a command to a button. When I click it I calls a method where I get the data I want from an API.What if I don't want to only bind the data at the view but also use these data in code behind?! 
Lets say this is my view :

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="HelloWorld.Pages.JohnDoePage"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Pages"
   <StackLayout Padding="20, 10" 
                HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Button Command="{Binding JohnDoe}"
                Text="Data about John Doe" />
   </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**the code behihnd:**

```
Models.Info info;
Models.Data data;
public JohnDoePage(Models.Info info)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    vm1 = new BranchesDetailsViewModel(info);
    BindingContext = vm1;
    this.info = info;

    //this is what I tried 
    var data = vm1.Dataa;
    var label = data.Adres;
    var label1 = new Label { Text = label, FontSize = 15, TextColor = Color.FromHex("#231f20"), HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center };

    stackB.Children.Add(label); /****/this code always breaks here. I guess because data.adress is null because the button it's not clicked so the comand it is not called****

    // i want to use the data here after I click the button
    //using the data after I click the button
 }
```

**the view model:**

```
Data _data;
public Data Data
{
    get { return _data; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _data) return;
        _data = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
public ICommand JohnDoe
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(async () =>
        {
            var Dataa = await _apiServices.InfoAboutJohnDOe();
        });
    }
}
```

And the service where I get the data I need is OK. I'm using the same  viewmodel for binding different commands, and I don't know if this is possible by the way so I'm stuck.

What I tried it looks like it's wrong because my app breakes. I think this happens because `data.adress` is null because the button it is not clicked when the page loads. I know I asked a similar question before and I thought I had the answer but it was not the right one so sorry again guys.

Any idea how can I handle this problem?? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: there are dozens of ways to approach this.  One might be to have an event on the VM that fires once the data is initialized - then your codebehind could subscribe to that event.  Or you could just used Binding everywhere.  Or use a Button Click handler instead of a command.

Comment: But I don't want to fire an event when the data is initialized because I need to wait for the user to click the button. After he clicks the button I want him to use the data in the code-behind for a few different things. Is there a way which check if the command is called so I can than use the data ?? @jason

Comment: I'm having immense trouble with this :/

Comment: it would probably easier to just use a click event in the code behind instead of a command.  Then your code behind would "know" the data has been loaded

Comment: So you say I should bind the command on the click event? Or don't use a command at all?

Comment: Now that I remember I also have another command which fires as soon as the page loads but it also breaks the app because somehow it first check the page for the data and than it loads. So it would be super helpful if I could handle the problem the way I described it @jason .What would your approach be?

Comment: again, I think just using a Clicked handler would be easier.  I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but you seem to be using lots of techniques that you really don't understand.  Do it the easy way and get it to work.  Once you've done that you can try using more complex methods.

Comment: I see your point, maybe you're right but I'm in the late phases of the development of my app, and I don't have time to change the whole way that it works. This is the only missing piece, where I need some user interaction, and that's why I need to use some code-behind, to manipulate the data, and then show it to the user. Is there any way which awaits for the button to "call" the command and then it executes the code in the file.xaml.cs ?? You don't have idea of how much an example would help me. :) @jason